# How to stop double NaN rendering as a string when used in GridViewDataColumn

Tags: .net, wpf, gridview, telerik, radgridview

I'm dynamically creating columns for a (telerik) RadGridView and I want double NaN values to show as a null string, currently they show as 'NaN'.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I was hoping there is a `DataFormatString` for this?

```
 var column = new GridViewDataColumn
 {
       Header = ExtractFriendlyName(member),
       DataType = valueType,
       DataMemberBinding = new Binding(member),
 };
```

Normally I would do this with a `FormatInfo` class, e.g:

```
var nfi = (NumberFormatInfo) NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();
nfi.NaNSymbol = "NaN";

double num = double.NaN;
string numString = System.Number.FormatDouble(num, null, nfi);
```

Comment: You might use a [binding converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) that converts from double to string.

Comment: Bingo! thanks, should have thought about that, obvious now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple binding converter would do what you want:

```
public class DoubleToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double)
        {
            double number = (double)value;
            value = double.IsNaN(number) ? string.Empty : number.ToString(culture);
        }

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}

...

DataMemberBinding = new Binding(member) { Converter = new DoubleToStringConverter() },
```